# what does a single variable line mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I found a syntax as following in an book about Angular.js.

```
$scope.selectedOrder; // what does this syntax mean?
$scope.selectOrder = function(order) {
  $scope.selectedOrder = order;
};
```

I know selectedOrder is an property of the $scope object.

But what is the purpose of " $scope.selectedOrder;".

I dont see any operation from this line. Could someone give me an hint?Thanks.

Comment: It's the same as `$scope.selectedOrder = undefined`, so they're just declaring it first and when it's selected it will be assigned `order` inside `$scope.selectOrder`.

Comment: Which book? Is that the entire code, nothing before it?

Comment: @gillesc I don't think that's how it works with object properties.

Comment: @gillesc: no, it's not a variable declaration. Unless the property is a getter with side effects (unlikely), or `$scope` is a proxy (very unlikely, if not impossible), it's a noop. It would not create the property if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Perhaps they meant to do $scope.selectedOrder = {};

Comment: The book is [Pro AngularJS](http://www.apress.com/9781430264484) on page 197.

Comment: Most probably it is supposed to set the initial value for the variable, as `$scope.selectedOrder = null;` or something. Without other details it mostly looks like a typo.

Comment: Yes I guess without that line `selectedOrder` would be undefined anyway as not existing on the object. Maybe it's purely for making the code clearer, all variables at the top so people are aware of the one created dynamically inside functions. Bit odd though I guess.

Comment: Actually, I thought they were the same variable too.. but one is selectedOrder, and the other is selectOrder. Two different variables.

Comment: Contact the author and ask. It may simply be a typo. Check here: http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=0636920028055

Comment: yes, they are not overwriten on the next line it's declared inside the function which is on the next line.

Comment: Anyways, $scope.selectedOrder; is not the same as $scope.selectedOrder = {}; I would bet its a typo, or a mistake.

Comment: See my answer below..

Comment: @pixelbits it is about showing what is publicly available. The property is set within the function but available through the function. It is about code readiblity.

Comment: @SecretService, fair enough. But couldn't the author have accomplished that by initializing the variable?

Comment: You mean to undefined? Probably more readable but then if it is already set, for instance in a constructor or from outside of the function of $scope, it would be overridden. $scope here might be the instance, sometimes also named that or self. The only way to expose variables is to set them like that. To show what is publicly available for developers one should declare them like this on top ... personally I do that on the top of the function ... usually with undefined, but I think I might stop now since it is unenneccasry really ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sometime use this pattern.

For instance if you have a "class":

```
    function Vehicle() {
            var $scope = this;

            $scope.tyres;  // Public property
            $scope.setTyres = function(num) {
                    $scope.tyres = num;
            }
    }

    var vehicle = new Vehicle();
    vehicle.setTyres(3);
    console.log("Number of tyres", vehicle.tyres)
```

You expose the tyres to be public. The reason it is declared outside is to show developers what is public, rather than let it remain hidden in the function setTyres.